# How to use Windows Biometric Framework API?

Tags: c#, .net, security, api

I want to use fingerprint in my application for user login. I found Windows Biometric Framework (WBF) API in MSDN. But my problem is they are use C or C++. I want to do it into my C# and .net 4.0 applications. Is there any example or tutorial (most welcome) or any advice for How to use WBF in .NET?

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Here some nice guy developed a wrapper for .NET https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/WinBiometricDotNet